# Implementation a Matlab loop to a python loop

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop

I am trying to convert the following Matlab loop to Python

```
N=7;
for j=1:10001
      E(j)=0.0+j*0.01;
       for i=1:N
         k(i)=sqrt(2*me*eV2J*meff*(E(j)-V(i)))/hbar;
      end
      for n=1:(N-1)
         p(1,1)=0.5*(1+k(n+1)/k(n))*exp(-1i*k(n)*L(n));
      end
      T(j)=(abs(1/P(1,1)))^2;
   end
```

I know that Python has `"for"` loop, like

```
E = []
K = []
for j in range(10001):
    for i in range(N):
        E.append(0.0+j*0.01)
        V.append(sqrt(2*me*eV2J*meff*(E(j)-V(i)))/hbar)
```

but I don't know how to `End` each loop as in Matlab?

Comment: Also note that the default in Python ranges is to start from 0, not 1. And you should use the numpy and matplotlib libraries to best approximate MatLab.

Comment: And note that in your Matlab code, the n-loop calculates p(1,1) several times

Comment: See [for loops](https://kkiesling.github.io/python-novice-gapminder-custom/06-for-loops/).